# how to set the softkeyboard to show german keys in android

Tags: android

i have to make an application in german, and in one of the activities i have to searching.

i have an edittext control for the same. but i want the user to input the text in german, how do set the softkeyboard to pop up with german keys?

thank you in advance.

EDIT: My application is using android 2.2.

Answer (score 1):

Well I know this is not really an answer but he comment box is a bit awkward to use for a longer reply.

I think you you are in for a bag of pain with this functionality.

1. Many Users do not appreciate if any application would change the system settings (and that is what we are talking about) without there consent.
2. Many Users don't use the standard keyboard and the function might not be available for all keyboard types.
3. The softkeyboard has changed significantly over time. The Gingerbread keyboard can change language on the fly. Older keyboard can't do that. You would have to account for that and you would need to test for all versions.
4. Switching to German will only half the story. You would have to **reliably** switch back to the users preferred keyboard (see point 1).

If at all I put an answer to this question then it is *“Wrong idea, don't do it!”* (Unless you develop for special needs users that is).

Comment: Adding: the user who uses it might allready have the german keyboard set as default?

Comment: Indeed. If it is a program for Germans I would expect that most have a German keyboard set by default. Or like me use something like Smart Keyboard Pro which allows quick changing between languages.

Comment: @martin: i wanted an answer. my client has requested for this to happen. the data that i am getting is in german and it is inserted into the database in german. if i do not have a german softkeyboard then the text he inputs for searching will never match the text in german which lies in my database. the user has specifically asked for a german keyboard.

Comment: @nanne: well the user may have such a settings but i have to look at all the conditions. by my way if the user has the keyboard set in german , well and good otherwise he will get it anyway. this is a more safe choice for me.

Comment: that would require you to virtually install a softkeyboard in with the app no?

Comment: @Dr.J: quite possible. Or changing the system set-up for the pre-installed keyboard. Maybe with time someone more in depth knowledge will answer this question. Might be interesting — for academic purpose.

Comment: @Martin, it's actually not too difficult to install a "keyboard" inside the app using just a mini-widget (and assuming a touch screen).  The problem comes from the logic in the keyboard etc.

Comment: @Dr.J: so there is no way for me to type german characters on my phone? i mean if set the locale or something...

Comment: Well you might be with `android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS` but as I said in point 1: It might raise an eyebrow with your future users. And you change the setting for **all** applications not just yours.

Comment: @user590849 you can force a locale change with `android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION` but this doesn't change the input only the display method.  You need to create your own softkeyboard or force a install & switch.  Which again is overreaching for an application.

Comment: @user590849:i am also faced this same problem in my application.i stuggled to get german language keyboard .if u know please reply here